# How to implement SWT, SAW, AS etc

Tags: arabic, arabtex

I was just wondering if there are any way to implement the arabic words of (Subhanahu wa ta'ala) (SAW), (AS), (RA) etc.. using arabtex?

Comment: I think you’d need a font containing special ligatures, and you’d want to use it with `xetex` or `luatex` rather than `pdftex`. Look into `arabluatex`, which can do much more than `arabtex`.

Comment: Hey @Thérèse, thanks for the suggestion. I switched over to arabluatex, and found out that SAW was equal to arbmark{slm}, but I couldn't figure out for the rest of them.

Comment: I’d use FontForge to inspect the glyphs and features available in my font, and then play with the `\newarbmark` command provided by `arabluatex` in order to use them.